# mattn/vim-gist plugin selecting single file from multi file gist

Tags: plugin

Using the https://github.com/mattn/vim-gist/ plugin, is it possible to open a specific file from a gist that has more than on file?

I'm asking because Visual Code Studio lets me select an individual file.

By default, vim-gist only opens the first file, and ALL files when a flag is set

```
let g:gist_get_multiplefile = 1
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I strongly suspect that you'll get the best answer by asking on GitHub